# Mosaico Template List Missing [error] Afform error: cannot process ~/afsearchMosaicoTemplateList/afsearchMosaicoTemplateList.aff.html: malformed enti

Tags: error, mosaico, templates, logs, flexmailer

Log viewer error [error] Afform error: cannot process ~/afsearchMosaicoTemplateList/afsearchMosaicoTemplateList.aff.html: malformed entity name ()

Problem I'm having is that when I go to: Mosaico templates my list of custom templates are gone as well as options to create new ones. I can; however, see them when I go to "new mailing" and start to send an email. I can edit them from there.

Steps I've taken so far:

Clear the cache - didn't help

Next steps:
Disabled mosaico and flex mailer extensions
deleted old mosaico file directory
refreshed ext.
enabled both flex mailer and mosaico
Still same error and problem

Other steps:
I tried re-installing the flex mailer too same as steps above, and it actually made everything worse, so I reverted back.

I've tried to look around in console, but I do not understand what the errors I'm getting mean or what to really look for. I'm attaching a screenshot of interface of mailer and console while looking at the mosaico template page.

If it helps, I'm also getting this log error but I think it is from Search Kit issues I'm having as it appears when I try to click "actions" and "print/merge" documents. But... Just in case other error is:  com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)[image]

[image]

Comment: have you found a solution? We're having the same issue after upgrading to Mosaico 2.10.

Comment: I'm also unable to see any Mosaico templates, though I don't have the same error message and my page looks a little different.

Comment: Yes. Civigrant was installed but disabled. It must be enabled or completely uninstalled. Weird, I know, but it is true. Something conflicts. Then, I had to uninstall and reinstall Mosaico, Search Kit, and Form Core (I believe that is the full list) and enable them 1 at a time in this order: Search kit, form core, then Mosaico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out was Civigrant was installed but disabled. It must be enabled or completely uninstalled. Something conflicts. I had to uninstall and reinstall Mosaico, Search Kit, and Form Core (I believe that is the full list) and enable them 1 at a time in this order: Search kit, form core, then Mosaico. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this. You should accept it as the answer since it resolved your issue! I was getting an unrelated error that mentioned lacking the civigrant table, so I'm hoping this fixes both problems.

Answer (score 0):

We hit this too, but found that uninstalling CiviGrant was sufficient, we did not uninstall/reinstall Mosaico etc (but maybe something else will bite us yet)

Answer (score 0):

Removing CiviGrant (from ext file system) and various iterations of disabling, uninstalling, deleting from ext file system (after taking a backup) of Search_kit, Afform, and Mosaico did not permit Mosaico templates to show up for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with a fresh CiviCRM 5.61.4. no Mosaico tempates show up after downloading and installing Mosaico.

When trying to create a template of type 'Newsletter' I receive this message in the UI:

ERROR
Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved

Removing CiviGrant (from ext file system) and various iterations of disabling, uninstalling, deleting from ext file system (after taking a backup) of Search_kit, Afform, and Mosaico did not permit Mosaico templates to show up for me.

Comment: Hi David I'm having same issue - did you manage to solve?

Comment: Hi Lesley, not yet, but I am picking this up again. I can say that file permissions alone are not the cause. In a test install I have made everything chmod -R 777 on the composer project directory - didn't help. 777 combined with removing civigrant from ./web/libraries/civicrm/core/ext/ and ./vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/ext/ also didn't help.